# How to get skype status as number or text? mystatus.skype.com doesnt work

Tags: status, skype

Im trying to show custom skype status icon on my website.

I found, that i can use url this:

http://mystatus.skype.com/username.txt but **it always returns "Offline"**.

I tried also with num and xml extension:

- http://mystatus.skype.com/username.num (always returns 1)
- http://mystatus.skype.com/username.xml (always says im offline).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It was all about privacy settings in Skype.

"*Allow my online status to be shown on the web*" is turned off by default. I had to turn it on in my Skype settings.

[FAQ on support.skype.com](https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA605/How-do-I-show-my-Skype-status-on-the-web) says

> To show your Skype status on the web:
>
> - Sign in to Skype
> - In the menu bar, click Skype > Privacy...  (on earlier versions, you can find this on Skype > Options > Privacy > Show Advanced Options)
> - Check Allow my online status to be shown on the web.

I dont understand, why there is no such information on page, where i can choose buttons :/